# perl code for identify usb events on windows

Tags: perl, usb

Could someone provide snippet/links for perl code for identification usb events (plug and unplug) on windows.

Answer (score 3):

Poll [DBD::WMI](http://p3rl.org/DBD::WMI) for changes with `Win32_USBControllerdevice`.